# using c# webrequest to interact with an asp.net mvc 3 website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, webrequest

I created a simple mvc3 site with a home controller with these actions.

```
public JsonResult Param(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            return Json(upper);
        }
        public ContentResult Param2(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            return Content( upper);
        }
        public JsonResult Param3(string id)
        {
            string upper = String.Concat(id, "ff");
            io gg = new io();
            gg.IOName = upper;
            return Json(gg);
        }
    }
    public class io
    {
         public string IOName {get;set;}
    }
```

How do I use c# webrquest to get the json and post to these action urls???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Darin's answer is good... but if you are looking to get the result from your method that returns a JSON payload, and you'd like that in C#... I'd do this:

```
var client = new WebClient();

var result = client.DownloadString("http://foo.com/home/param3/SomeID");

var serialzier = new JavaScriptSerializer();

io MyIOThing = serialzier.Deserialize<io>(result);
```

From there, you can have access to `MyIOThing.IOName`.

The `JavaScriptSerializer` is in the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly, in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace.

Answer (score 5):

A [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) is much easier than a [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx):

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "id", "123" }
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://foo.com/home/param", data);
}
```